# How to fit desktop view to phone screen in Chrome for Android as it happens in Safari on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, safari

I noticed that Safari on iOS 15.5 can auto fit webpages in desktop view, I'm attaching a screenshot from LinkedIn for example as shown below:

First I browsed the website and chose the following option:

[image: Request Desktop Website]

after that it was displayed as below, notice that it was resized to fit the phone screen:

[image: LinkedIn on Safari]

I tried the same thing with Chrome, on Android 11 as below:

[image: Desktop Site Chrome for Android]

But when I try to do the same on Chrome for Android 11, it doesn't fit the page to screen as shown below:

[image: LinkedIn on Chrome]

And unfortunately I cannot find an official version of Safari for Android nor could I find other browsers that have that feature.

So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different browsers I found the only one that resizes web views to fit phone screen, it's [Maxthon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mx.browser)